# Returned error: transaction underpriced in BEP-20 Token transaction

Tags: node.js, web3js, binance-smart-chain, bep20

I tried to transfer my BEP-20 token using web3.js

I deployed new BEP-20 token and could send the tokens to another address using MetaMask.

I tried to transfer in nodejs. I followed guide to send token.

Below is my code

```
const sendBEP20Transaction =  async () => {

  var Web3 = require('web3');
  var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org'))

  var myAddress = '0xF3b6A45AFbC5892a70EA7ca5b10d61A500BeCeC1';
  var toAddress = '0xa5915F48DDD3A7D25Daf1AeBd5Df677389b679bA';
  var privateKey = 'd5...';  
  var abiArray = [...];
  var contractAddress = '0xcB39dAF817EC0BaDDF78719dA24768b3fe81A7b5';
  var amount = web3.utils.toHex(10)

 
  var count;

  await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress).then(function (v) { 
    console.log('count: ', v); 
    count = v 
  })

  let account = web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(privateKey);
  var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress, {
    from: myAddress,
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(5),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(80000),
  })

  contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, amount).send({ 
    from: '0xF3b6A45AFbC5892a70EA7ca5b10d61A500BeCeC1',
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(5),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(80000),
  })
  .then()
  .catch(console.error);
}
```

When I run this code I got error 'Returned error: transaction underpriced'

```
Error: Returned error: transaction underpriced
    at Object.ErrorResponse (F:\bep20_test\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:28:19)
    at F:\bep20_test\node_modules\web3-core-requestmanager\lib\index.js:304:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (F:\bep20_test\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib\index.js:98:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (F:\bep20_test\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (F:\bep20_test\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (F:\bep20_test\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (F:\bep20_test\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  data: null
}
```

Anyone please help me, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The "transaction underpriced" error occurs, when you're trying to replace a transaction and the replacing gas price is too low.

See this for the solution and in-depth explanation:

[transaction underpriced in BEP-20 Token transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67972674/transaction-underpriced-in-bep-20-token-transaction)